# How to start the transition animation after the user sees the collection view cell?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uiviewanimationtransition

i am creating a simple walkthrough page and using collectionview for it. I want show to users a simple transition animation in the last cell.

I use the willdisplaycell method to do this but the animation is not happening.

Can you help with this?

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let lastCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: signcellid, for: indexPath) as! SignCell

    if indexPath.row == pageImages.count {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 0.5, options: .curveEaseOut) {
            lastCell.logoLabel.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 200, y: 200)
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure that method is getting called and that the condition is being met?

Comment: How about: `indexPath.row == pageImages.count - 1`

Comment: Yes I check with breakpoint @LeoDabus  btw when i call the animation in cell it happens but not here

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. I don't understand why @Rob